# Valid to have span around legend in a fieldset?

Tags: html

I'm trying to style the legend in a fieldset and im running into a lot of troubles. As my site is responsive and the legend text length varies I can't achieve what I want consistently with margins, relative or absolute positioning.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <label>Label</label>
    <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

All I need is for the legend to behave like a normal block level. The only way ive found to do this is to wrap the legend in a span. Is this valid HTML? Im assuming that there arn't any CSS only solutions?

```
<fieldset>
    <span>
        <legend>Title</legend>
    </span>
    <label>Label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you tried validating it? Previous questions of yours indicate that you're aware of the W3C validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `legend` element is only valid as **the first child of a `fieldset` element.** [See the spec here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element)

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmukW/1/) with your code that wraps the `<legend>` element in a `<span>`, and it [causes an error in the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2FjmukW%2F1%2Fshow%2Flight%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices).

Another solution is to use CSS to hide the legend from view:

```
legend { display: none; }
```

Then you can create and style your own custom headings for the fieldset.